# Create Random Bubbles in android app

Tags: android

I have aproblem with my app creating random sized bubbles using this method

```
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {

            // TODO - Implement onSingleTapConfirmed actions.
            // You can get all Views in mFrame using the
            // ViewGroup.getChildCount() method
            for(int i=0; i < mFrame.getChildCount(); i++){
                BubbleView bubbleNew= (BubbleView) mFrame.getChildAt(i);

                if(bubbleNew.intersects(event.getX(), event.getY())){
                bubbleNew.stop(true);

                }
                }
                BubbleView bubbleNew= new BubbleView(mFrame.getContext(),event.getRawX(),event.getRawY());
                bubbleNew.start();
                mFrame.addView(bubbleNew); 
                return false;
                }

    });
}
```

the problem is when i touch anywhere the bubbles are created at the same position (top left)
How can i recover it ?

Comment: What makes you think it wouldn't get created at the top left position? i.e. where do you tell the parent where it should draw your `View`?

Comment: bubbleNew= new BubbleView(mFrame.getContext(),event.getX(pID),event.getY(pID));  //updated  here i told the parent to create a bubble at (x,y) of the tap any suggestions??

Comment: The problem is that you probably don't do anything with the coordinates in your BubbleView. You need to specifically tell the parent where to draw the view, not the view where it should draw itself.